# Value not compatible when doing merge in DB2

Tags: php, sql, db2

I'm trying to perform a merge based on a parameter from a previous select within a php script but I"m getting the error "SQL0408 - Value for column,variable, or paramter QUANTITY not compatible"

In my destination table QUANTITY is data type INTEGER

In my select query, I'm casting the value as an int (which it already is in the table, I'm just casting everything to be safe)

```
cast(MAX(orqtyc) as int) AS QUANTITY,
```

Then in my MERGE I'm casting as INT

```
MERGE INTO HNORMANTEST.PLACEMENTS AS P
        USING(VALUES(

            CAST(:QUANTITY as INT),

        ))
```

Using this param

```
$params = [

    ":QUANTITY" => $row["QUANTITY"],

];
```

Why would it say it's not compatible?

Comment: `MERGE` on DB2 is not consistently implemented.  Are you using the `luw` or `zOS` flavor?  Specifically `VALUES()` does not work on zOS.

Comment: I'm not even sure, actually. It's on the iseries is all I know. I'm implementing It the same way as I have in the past. Would it be better to not cast again in the merge?

Comment: and it's failing at the line where I prepare my merge @Stavr00

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it by putting directly value instead of via param and see if it works or not.

Another thing you can try is remove the first casting which may not be needed. As you said QUANTITY is already a INT datatype.

Please try both the variation. If both variation givens same error then there might be some product limitation/bug.

You need to pass on the DB2 version where you have tried to look further in it.